# Having trouble declaring const

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am currently developing a component in reactjs and I ran into a parsing error in which the keyword const, let and var are not being recognizes. Any insight to fixing this problem ?

I've tried installing es6 package to the react project.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/Calendar.js
  Line 12:  Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'const'

  10 |
  11 |     state={
> 12 |         const localizer = BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment)
     |         ^
  13 |     }
  14 |
  15 |
```

I expect to use the variable with no parsing error.

Comment: are you using babel?

Comment: You can't use const with an object literal's key. Try with `state = { localizer:BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment) }`

Comment: state is an `object` which is supposed to have key/value pair, why you need const before localizer ?

Comment: Use `const state = { localizer: 'BigCalendar'};` or get rid of the `{}`. You are mixing object literals with variables..

Answer (score 2):

localizer is a key not a value. you can make it's value a const outside of the component's state and use that inside the state, but you can't declare a variable inside an object like that. You could do this...

```
const localizer = BigCalendar.momentLocalizer(moment);

state = {
    localizer: localizer
};
```

Comment: Or to make it even more terse, with ES6 syntax:`state = { localizer }`